# removing duplicated chars from string in C

Tags: c, string

My program has to look for duplicated chars (that comes one after another) and remove them. So my program does work, but in case I put "PLLNSIS", I get "PLNSISS". I overwrite the char that I find out is duplicated, but in the end, i recieve a copy of the last char.

```
 void main() 
    {
        int length;
        char *myString;
        printf("Enter the length of the string \n");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        myString = (char*)malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
        assert(myString);
        printf("Now enter the string: (max %d letters) \n", length);
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); //flushing the buffer
        fgets(myString, length+1, stdin); //calling the input function
        no_Straight_Letters(myString);
        free(myString);
    }     

       void no_Straight_Letters(char *myString)
        {
            int i, j = 0, length = strlen(myString);
            for (i = 1; i < length-1; i++)
            {
                if (myString[j] == myString[i])
                {
                    myString[j] = myString[i];
                    myString[i] = '\0';
                }
                    else myString[++j] = myString[i];
            }
            myString[length] = '\0'; //last char of the string
            printf("And the new string is.... -->  ");
            puts(myString);
        }
```

I found out the cause but when I fix it, I get nothing on the screen.

Comment: What did you add to "fix" it?

Comment: Two times UB: 1.) It's `int main(void)` at least; 2.) The prototype to `no_Straight_Letters()` is missing.

Comment: _"I found out the cause"_ so why didn't you tell readers what you think it is??

Comment: Hint: In case you "remove" a letter you are shortening the string, so the `0`-terminator's position would need to change, wouldn't it?

Comment: @underscore_d Because I don't think I can explain it good enough, but if you insist - when I place '\0' instead of a duplicated char, then the program comparing the next char with the last char that wasn't a duplicate. then she overwrite the new char instead of the '\0' and over that progress goes over and over again. Hope I could clear myself.

Comment: @OfekPintok.: This is the problem you had. You can check it.

Comment: You might want to walk through the code using pencil and paper.  Draw come cells represent an array and track the indexes i and j and go through the loop a few times.  I suspect you might have bigger issues than just what you described.  I think you might need one more index to track....

Comment: @dernst That was the first step for solving this question and even though, I did not know how to stop the "overflowing" of the "new" duplicated chars. that something you can't see on a paper, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
 myString[length] = '\0';
```

It will be

```
 myString[++j] = '\0';
```

This works because at the end of the looping `j` points to the last valid character. Then if you increase it and put `\0` there - it will make the string.

You can emulate the behavior of having `\n` with this small addition (which is not likely to be needed).

```
myString[++j]='\n';
myString[++j]=0;
```

Also as a small modification you can remove the redundant assignment in your code. it's unnecessary.

```
if (myString[j] == myString[i])
{
    myString[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

First, you miss the last character; you might not have noticed it, because the last character of your `fgets`-input is probably a newline which you do not see. So you'd iterate like `for (i = 1; i <= length-1; i++)`.

Second, you cut off the string at `length`, which is larger then the final string; use `myString[j+1] = '\0'` instead.

Minor issue: The code in your `if` is useless, you can omit it.

```
void no_Straight_Letters(char *myString)
{
    int i, j = 0, length = strlen(myString);
    for (i = 1; i <= length-1; i++)
    {
        if (myString[j] != myString[i])
           myString[++j] = myString[i];
    }
    myString[j+1] = '\0'; //last char of the string
    printf("And the new string is.... -->  '%s'",myString);
}


int main()
{
    char myString[] = "PLLNSISSSHERBERTTTA";
    no_Straight_Letters(myString);
}
```

Comment: Hey that's expected...you can't do `<length-1` you dont have `\n`. :)

Comment: @coderredoc: right, that's the issue. I think `no_Straight_Letters`  should also work for input without a trailing newline; So it needs to be `<=`...

Comment: Yes..that's why. In fact my solution also works for this input. But really now all the changes are minor (to consider `\n` or not consider it)...